# Can OS X services be split up across multiple OS X Servers at different locations?

Tags: osx-server

My company has two offices, in two different cities.  I'd like to use a colo to host our OS X Server, which will manage Open Directory data, device management, VPN, shared file storage, mail, messaging, and most of the other services that OS X Server offers.

At each office, then, I'd *like* to have a Mac mini running OS X Server to manage that office's LAN and, hopefully, be that office's hub for Software Update service.

Is it possible to divvy up services across multiple OS X Servers in this way?  If so, are there any pitfalls I should be wary of going forward?

Comment: I have the same question... DNS can be split, OpenDirectory LDAP too, can't say the same about mail.

Answer (score 1):

I know Software Update service cannot be replicated. You can however, run multiple Software Update servers. You just have to point the client to which Software Update server you want to use.